# How do I change UPPERCASES to Correct casing for specific words?

Tags: powershell, rename

Hi I need to change the cases of the specific words

Example:

- RX PPLLC - Dr. Smith - John Smith - OH - PAIN - Lidocaine
- RX PPLLC - Dr. Smith - John Smith - OH - PAIN - Fenoprofen
- RX PPLLC - Dr. Smith - John Smith - OH - DERMATITIS - Diflorasone
- RX PPLLC - Dr. Smith - John Smith - OH - SCAR - Silvex Pad

Should be like this:

- RX PPLLC - Dr. Smith - John Smith - OH - Pain - Lidocaine
- RX PPLLC - Dr. Smith - John Smith - OH - Pain - Fenoprofen
- RX PPLLC - Dr. Smith - John Smith - OH - Dermatitis - Diflorasone
- RX PPLLC - Dr. Smith - John Smith - OH - Scar - Silvex Pad

I have tried this:

`get-childitem -recurse | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace "PAIN","Pain" }`
`get-childitem -recurse | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace "SCAR","Scar" }`
`get-childitem -recurse | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace "DERMATITIS","Dermatitis" }`

Now the question is, is there anyway that I could consolidate this into one code? The words in the end is not always one word 2 or more for other file names.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are needing to rename your files using `TitleCase`. Note, converting to `TitleCase` does not work for all upper. So, we will need to put the string `ToLower()`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Path" -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace "$($_.Name)", "$((Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($_.Name.ToLower()))"}
```

Another note, this will change "RX PPLLC" to `TitleCase` as well. If you need to ignore that, you might need to use `substring` to get around it.

Update: -- If you want to keep "RX PPLLC":

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Test" -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {
    $lefSide = $_.Name.Substring(0,$_.Name.IndexOf('-'))
    $rightSide = $_.Name.Substring($_.Name.IndexOf('-') + 1)
    $rightSide = $((Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($rightSide.ToLower()))
    $newName = $leftSide + $rightSide
    $_.Name -replace "$($_.Name)", "$newName"    
}
```

There are much better ways of doing this. Basically, this will take the file name into two strings (a left side and right side). It will change the right then put it back into a variable called `$newName` . This will only work if your file name contains a `-`. If you wanted to handle for those situations, you would need a condition or a regEx... this is just a quick example

Comment: How do I use substring for this?

Comment: @GabrielBalenton Updated a quick example.

Comment: That code would apply the TitleCase to everything after the first `-`, changing `OH` to `Oh`. I would do this: `$parts = $_.Name.Split '-'; $parts[4] = (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($parts[4].ToLower());$NewName = $parts -join '-'`

Comment: Yes, that would change the `OH` as well to `TitleCase` . Assuming that is a state, night take that into consideration as well.